# Can't find stored session after refresh

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, express-session, session-storage

I'm trying to create a simple logging app with  express-session, connect-mongodb-session and apollo-server-express and apollo-client for UI.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Here is my login function:
[image: 3]

Here I'm finding session from the context to use it for protected routes in UI:
[image: 4]

It works on GraphQL Playground:
[image: 5]

And I can store cookie on UI as well:
[image: 6]

Here is UI code:

[image: 7]
[image: 8]

The problem is that after refresh, cookie does not diaper, but ItIsMe querie does not work as intended.
Meaning when I'm requesting ItIsMe querie it returns null unlike GraphQL Playground behavior
[image: 8]

If anyone knows where the problem could be, please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an SSR on client side.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/10311